# php ( function.php) file function call in another file

Tags: php

I have a page function.php and call this function in another page view.php but function not call properly
Here is the function.php code

```
 <?php
function head1()
{
  global $title;
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <header>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>WhiteFlower| florida web design</title>
</header>
}
head1();
?>
```

Second php file

```
<?php
 include "function.php";
 head1();
 ?>
```

This is code of another file view.php
I am new in php so I cannot understand how it works properly

Comment: why do you have function call on `function.php` and also on `view.php` ?

Comment: No i just want to call in view.php

Comment: Then remove the function call from function.php

Answer (score 0):

This page is showing error because you are have error in your function you should echo your html  or return them you are writing like html in php block

your code

```
<?php

    function head1()
    {
      global $title;
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <header>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>WhiteFlower| florida web design</title>
    </header>
    }
?>
```

Replace with this

```
<?php

    function head1()
    {
      global $title;
    echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <header>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>WhiteFlower| florida web design</title>
    </header>';
    }
?>
```

please let me know if your error is resolved or not and also attach a snapshot of error we will figure it out

Comment: what was the issue how you solved it please share here it will helpful for other